# When a container mounts host's Docker socket, can it also have access to host's credentials?

Tags: docker

I am running a Docker container X which itself needs to spawn a new container Y. As suggested in docs, I bind mount `/var/run/docker.sock` inside X, so that X can communicate with the host's Docker. When X tries to do `docker run SOME_IMAGE`, it is actually the host that spawns a container from `SOME_IMAGE`, not X. So far so good.

Now I want to use images from a private repo. On the host, `docker run MY.PRIVATE.DOCKER.REGISTRY.com/SOME_IMAGE` will automatically pull `SOME_IMAGE` from `MY.PRIVATE.DOCKER.REGISTRY.com`. However the private repo requires me to authenticate, which has the result of writing my credentials in `~/.docker/config.json`. After this, the host can pull images normally.

However, despite the host being authenticated, container X still cannot pull images. I'm assuming this is because X doesn't have a `~/.docker/config.json`. I also don't want to authenticate inside every single Docker container.

If I also bind-mount `~/.docker/config.json`, will this allow containers to transparently pull from the private repo without worrying about authentication, so long as the host is authenticated? Are there any significant downsides to this?

Comment: I guess it should work. Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Writing your question: 10mn. Testing the scenario you described: 2mn. Why don't you try (and come up with a better question if your are still stuck) ?

Comment: You could `docker create` a container bind-mounting the host's `/`, and then just `docker cp` the file you need.  Relatedly, you can `docker cp` content of your choice over the host's `/etc/shadow` file, and trivially take over the host that way.  Are you _sure_ you need one container to launch another?

Answer (score 0):

yes

```sh
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/me/.docker:/root/.docker -it docker sh

/ $ docker pull private-registry/name:tag
# pulls the image
```

If I bind mount the configuration it works. It won't work with all configurations, some configurations call out to auth commands that provide the credentials for the remote repo. You'll need to make sure that those commands are available within the container.